# Oracle 10g, how to query numerical value, (years) with specific limits on results

Tags: oracle10g, conditional-operator

So the question I am posed with is to take the years produced of all of the movies in two genre's, (SH and CH) an then print out a list of all the movies, (title and year), that were produced before any of the movies in my specific genre were produced. I have this:

```
SELECT x.title "Title", x.yr "Year"
FROM movies x
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT x FROM movies y 
WHERE y.genre IN ('SH', 'CH') AND y.yr < x.yr)
ORDER BY yr;
```

but it's producing all sorts of titles that were produced during and after the two genres had any of their movies produced. I would think that the less than would limit the results to anything under 1965, (the oldest move in either genre), but it doesn't, but if I use the greater than operator it does, (although it still pumps out newer results as well, so that doesn't work either)

Does anybody see what it is I am missing here? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Anyone got input, or can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
I just needed to use the operator differently

```
WHERE yr <
(SELECT insert stuff here); // this is homework so I can't post the full code
```

Seems I was just over complicating things.